# What's inappropriate for chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I just got chat banned for the word below, presumingly because it's "Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended."

https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/38830429/history

---

So what is considered "inappropriate" for chat?

Comment: Consider that many people use Stack Exchange sites and chat in professional environments. If what you post is not appropriate in such an environment, it is likely not appropriate for chat.

Comment: Hence why I didn't directly type the content here, and instead linked it -- But I'm really failing to see how it's offensive. Childish? Sure, amusing? Definitely, but not offensive. Unless we are taking the point of view of non-mammalian users into account....

Comment: That **you** don't find it offensive doesn't mean that someone else might not get offended. We are a global and diversified community.

Comment: @Oded but not civilised, if the only way of letting someone know you don't like their remark, is to instantly remove them from any kind of discussion of said remark.

Comment: @djsmiley2k The mark of a civil society is not one where there aren't consequences for acting inappropriately.  In fact, you have that backwards.

Comment: Nope, it's that the consequences match the offense.

Comment: Your link is broken. Would you mine taking a screenshot of what you typed?

Comment: @AnthonyPham not broken, deleted. Moderators can see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, the rules are the same in chat as on the main sites. So if you want to be sure, don't use any words in chat you wouldn't also be comfortable using on the main sites.

In practice, chat is much less strict that the main sites. Most of the time, some mild cursing or profanity won't have any consequences.

One important aspect is that SE chat is rather public, it's not just a conversation between a few friends. You should assume that you have an audience there, and other people are reading the conversation. You don't know *everyone*
that reads the conversation, even if you know the other active participants well enough to judge if they would take offense or not.

Just mentioning the word "nipples" isn't against the chat rules in my opinion, and I wouldn't have flagged that or validated the flag. And in your case, one moderator also unsuspended you pretty much immediately, so at least one moderator disagreed strongly with that flag.

Chat moderation is pretty much random because there are hundreds of users that can validate flags, with very different opinions on how chat moderation should work.

Comment: But you've missed the point. I'd happily say the word 'Nipples' here too - I don't find it offensive, most people don't find it offensive. It's not a unsafe for work word so I really don't understand why the people who validated the flag validated it....

**Chat moderation is pretty much random because there are hundreds of users that can validate flags, with very different opinions on how chat moderation should work.**..... yeah, exactly my point.